# Understanding ArrayAdapter used for Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using an ArrayAdapter for my listview, and there is something I do not really understand. Here is an example of my code

```
      class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

            public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
                super(context, R.layout.list_item, items);
            }


            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = convertView;

                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi;
                    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }
                ...some code here....
            }
       }
```

and my question is: why do I need to inflate layout in "getView" if I already set its Id in the constructor in "super" call.? After I set the layout-Id via "super", is this Id stored somewhere in ArrayAdapter? So I do not understand what this "resource id" in super call for..

Thanks for explaining :)
Best Regards

Comment: you are overriding getView. you'll notice that the value you pass in the constructor is actually totally ignored. You could, however, have something like `v = super.getView(...)` and not call inflate yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `getView` when you want to display in your listview something of different from just a text. Example when you want to want to show an image with a text (You know Whatsapp? It's a listview).

If you don't need it, maybe you don't need to override ArrayAdapter at all. Just use the class as it is and stop. You can use any object you want, ArrayAdapter will use `toString()` of the class passed to show the text.

```
ArrayAdapter<Items> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Items> ();
listView.setAdapter (adapter);
```

use `Items.toString()` to say what you want to show as text.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I understand that I need to overwrite it for displaying custom content. But what I do not understand, that what for is a parameter of the Resource Id in "super()", if Its never used.. even its the same, that I would inflate later in getView()

Comment: It's used by the default getView method. If you don't override it you already have a working getView.